# How do I set or change the SMTP Message-ID with javax.mail?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

How can I set the SMTP message-id while sending mails with `javax.mail`. My mail server is reporting something like this:

```
1 <= me@domain.com H=mail (host) [192.168.1.4] P=esmtp S=142014
     id=2043289758.9.1322829290422.JavaMail.thor@developer.local
2 => sombodey@else R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx00.t-online.de [194.25.134.8]
3 Completed
```

I want to set the `id=2043289758.9.1322829290422.JavaMail.thor@developer.local` before sending it. Is this possible? The email it created like this:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "192.168.1.4");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
session.setDebug(false);
Message msg = createMsg();
Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe this section of the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#msgid) answers your question:

> **Q:** I set a particular value for the Message-ID header of my new message, but when I send this message that header is rewritten.
>
> **A:** A new value for the Message-ID field is set when the saveChanges method is called (usually implicitly when a message is
>   sent), overwriting any value you set yourself. If you need to set your
>   own Message-ID and have it retained, you will have to create your own
>   MimeMessage subclass, override the updateMessageID method and use an
>   instance of this subclass.
>
> ```
> class MyMessage extends MimeMessage {
>     ...
>
>     protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
>   setHeader("Message-ID", "my-message-id");
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 11):

According to [Oracle's FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#msgid), when you send the message or call saveChanges, the Message-Id header set by the updateMessageID() method, which overrides any value you might have already set.

To set your own value, you will need to create a sub-class of MimeMessage and implement your own updateMessageID() function:

```
class MyMimeMessage extends MimeMessage {
    ...
    protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
        setHeader("Message-ID", "my-message-id");
    }
    ...
}
```

I was able to use this technique to suppress or eliminate the Message-Id header like this:

```
@Override
protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
    removeHeader("Message-Id");
}
```

This was useful for Mailgun, which sets the Message-Id themselves if you don't set one.

Answer (score 3):

You can also save message changes and set a custom Message-ID before sending.
Steps:

1. Create `MimeMessage message` and Set its data.
2. `message.saveChanges();`
3. `message.setHeader("Message-ID", yourCustomMessageId);`
4. Send the message.

This is useful with Spring's `JavaMailSender` or in other situations where it is difficult to override `MimeMessage`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No new class required... Just created immediately before calling the `.send()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(s) {
    @Override
    protected void updateMessageID() { } // Prevent MimeMessage from overwriting our Message-ID
};
msg.setHeader("Message-ID", "MyOwnMessageID");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the complete code for implementing the custom id in the message

```
public class SendMessage{

     private String idMessage;

     private void sendEmail() {
         //...
         // Create de session
         //...

         Message message = new MyMessage(session);

         //...
         // Prepare the body of the message, attachments, etc.
         //...

         // assign custom message id
         this.idMessage = “My own ID”;

         //send
         Transport.send(message);
    }

    class MyMessage extends MimeMessage {

        public MyMessage(Session session) {
           super(session);
        }

        protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
            setHeader("Message-ID", this.idMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Message-ID is a unique identifier for a digital message, most commonly a globally unique identifier used in email. No two different messages must ever have the same Message-ID.
MimeMessage will generate Message-ID while creating the message. It is possible to override message id by using MimeMessage.setHeader("Message-ID", "customMessageId");

Comment: All the other answers say that any message ID set using this method will be overwritten by `updateMessageID()`. They all provide ways preventing that from happening. Has something changed that means that the other answers are unnecessary, or is this answer just incorrect?

Comment: Setting the Message-ID in the Header worked for me. I have not implemented the way which others mentioned