# Set MessageId in header before sending mail

Tags: java, email, grails, groovy, jakarta-mail

I am sending mails from my application using JAVA mail on smtp server, port 465. My need is that, I have to set Message-ID before sending mail. I did some R&D and found the code below. I had override the method `updateMessageID()` of `MimeMessage`

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class CustomMimeMessage extends MimeMessage {

public CustomMimeMessage(Session session) {
    super(session);
}

@Override
protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {

    setHeader("Message-ID", "message id");

   }
}
```

And then I had made an instance of `CustomMimeMessage` in my service and then invoke `updateMessageID()` method using that instance, but I still get the Message-ID generated by gmail.

Comment: That probably means that when the mail passes by gmail's servers, gmail modifies that header before forwarding it to its destination. Can't you use some other header?

Comment: If you turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), do you see the correct Message-ID header in the message being sent?  It would be really bad if Gmail is modifying the Message-ID on messages passing through it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
setHeader("Message-ID", "message id");
```

you are trying to set "message id" as Message-ID which is quite wrong you have to set a unique id that qualify all the rules of the message id ([Read This](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4)).

Try this..,.

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class CustomMimeMessage extends MimeMessage {
Session session;
private static int id = 0;

public CustomMimeMessage(Session session) {
    super(session);
    this.session=session;
}

@Override
protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
    setHeader("Message-ID", "<" + getUniqueMessageIDValue(session) + ">");
}

public static String getUniqueMessageIDValue(Session ssn) {
    String suffix = null;

    InternetAddress addr = InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(ssn);
    if (addr != null)
        suffix = addr.getAddress();
    else {
        suffix = "javamailuser@localhost"; // worst-case default
    }

    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

    // Unique string is <hashcode>.<id>.<currentTime>.JavaMail.<suffix>
    s.append(s.hashCode()).append('.').append(getUniqueId()).append('.').
      append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append('.').
      append("JavaMail.").
      append(suffix);
    return s.toString();
    }

private static synchronized int getUniqueId() {
        return id++;
}
}
```

Comment: At first, this didn't work for me, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13199695/581205) helped. I missed the part concerning overriding.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar but sending from the local host instead. This Might help.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class SendEmail {
/**
 * Sends an email based on paramaters passed to it.
 * 
 * @param toWho - the recipiants email address 
 * @param fromWho - the senders email address
 * @param subject - the subject line of the email  
 * @param body - the email message body  
 * @return void
 * @throws AddressException
 * @throws MessageingException
 */
public void sendMail(String toWho, String subject, String body, String fromWho) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    // Setting Properties
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*"); // trusting all server certificates
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    // Set From header
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromWho));
    // Set to header
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toWho));
    // Header set subject
    message.setSubject(subject);
    // Message Body
    message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    // Send message
    Transport.send(message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set message-id to MimeMessage before call Transport.send() by extending MimeMessage like this.

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MyMimeMessage extends MimeMessage {

    public MailorMimeMessage(Session session) {
        super(session);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
        if (getHeader("Message-Id") == null) {
            super.updateMessageID();
        }
    }
}
```

And set custom message-id.

```
message.setHeader("Message-Id","<MY-MESSAGE-ID>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom id with .(dot) before left side of '@'. It worked for me.
Check the following code snippet:

```
public class CustomMimeMessage extends MimeMessage {

Session session;
private static int id = 0;

public CustomMimeMessage(Session session) {
    super(session);
    this.session = session;
}

protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
    debugLog("Calling updateMessageID()");
    setHeader("Message-ID", "<" + getUniqueMessageIDValue(session) + ">");
}

public static String getUniqueMessageIDValue(Session ssn) {
    String suffix = null;

    InternetAddress addr = InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(ssn);
    if (addr != null) {
        testLog("InternetAddress = " + addr.toString());
        String address = addr.getAddress();
        if (address.contains("@")) {
            address = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf("@"), address.length());
            suffix = address;
        }
    }

    if (suffix == null) {
        suffix = "@mail";// worst-case default
    }
    testLog("suffix Address = " + suffix);

    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    s.append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append("")
            .append(getUniqueId()).append(suffix).append(".sm");
    testLog("NEW MESSAGE-ID: " + s.toString());
    return s.toString();
}

private static synchronized int getUniqueId() {
    return id++;
}
```

For more details, Please refer the following RFC's. These are really helpful for creating syntax for Custom message-id.

1. [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4)
2. [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4)

Hope this would also work for you.