# java- undelivered mails:get email id of which emails are undelivered

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-notifications, email-delivery

I have been doing count for emails which are Read-Reciept,NotRead,AutoReplied,Out of Office,Replied Delivered and undelivered mails with following code.But I want email ids on which the mails are undelivered.

To get email for undelivered mails I can do it by parsing the content for that email but that will be very lengthy task.Please help me with a better solution

```
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray dataCollection = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject data = null;
        try {

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(props.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"), userid, password);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            int countDelivered = 0;
            int countUndelivered = 0;
            int countRead = 0;
            int countAutoReply = 0;
            int countUnRead = 0;
            int countReplied = 0;

            jo.put("TotalMessage", inbox.getMessageCount());

            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(0,50);

            for (Message message : messages) {

                boolean undelMsgs = message.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("Mail Delivery")
                        || message.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("Postmaster")
                        || message.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("Failed") 
                        || message.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("Failure")
                        || message.getSubject().contains("(Failure)")
                        || message.getSubject().contains("Undeliverable:");

                boolean readMsgs = message.getSubject().contains("Read:") 
                        && !message.getSubject().contains("Not read:")
                        && !message.getSubject().contains("Un-Read:") 
                        && !message.getSubject().contains("UnRead:") ;

                boolean unreadMsgs = message.getSubject().contains("Un-Read:") 
                        || message.getSubject().contains("UnRead:") 
                        || message.getSubject().contains("Not read:");

                boolean autoReply = message.getSubject().contains("Automatic") 
                        || message.getSubject().contains("Reply:") 
                        || message.getSubject().contains("[Auto-Reply]")
                        || message.getSubject().contains("Out of Office");

                boolean replied = message.getSubject().contains("RE:");
                data = new JSONObject();

                if (undelMsgs)
                    countUndelivered++;
                else
                    countDelivered++;

                if (readMsgs)
                    countRead++;
                if (unreadMsgs)
                    countUnRead++;

                if (autoReply)
                    countAutoReply++;

                if (replied)
                    countReplied++;
                data = new JSONObject();
                data.put("subject=", message.getAllHeaders());
                data.put("from=", message.getFrom()[0]);

                dataCollection.put(data);
            }

            inbox.close(true);
            System.out.println("Done....");
            store.close();
            data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("Delivered=", countDelivered);
            data.put("Undelivered=", countUndelivered);
            data.put("Read=", countRead);
            data.put("AutoReply=", countAutoReply);
            data.put("Replied=", countReplied);
            data.put("UnRead=", countUnRead);

            dataCollection.put(data);

            jo.put("tableData", dataCollection);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jo;
```

You may find this code very willy and purpose oriented but to get this much also I didn't have any solution available online.

Comment: message.getHeader("X-Failed-Recipients") is one solution

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's no golden Rule for that. It depends on what the failing SMTP server choses to send you back.

But there's hope: [MultipartReport](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/MultipartReport.html)

If you get a hold of this inside your message **and** the other SMTP chose to add (at least the headers of) the original message, you could access it this way:

```
  for (Message message : messages) {
     if(message instanceof MimeMessage) {
        MimeMessage mime = (MimeMessage)message;
        Object content = mime.getContent();
        if(content instanceof MultipartReport) {
           MultipartReport dsn = (MultipartReport)content;
           MimeMessage m = dsn.getReturnedMessage();
           if(m != null) {
              String originalMessageId = m.getMessageID();
               //TADAA!
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

In all other cases you have to resort to other ideas.

- The MultiPartReport.getReport() might be a DeliveryNotification and the Headers might contain a original-envelope-id-field with your message id.
- Maybe there's an "In-Reply-To" Header?
- Maybe there's a "References" Header?

Both could contain your original Message-ID. But might not even be set, so you'd be down to parsing the report text itself.

Comment: can i send my own message id to identify the reply and notification, like for which mail the reply is

Comment: Check here how to obtain message id: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8366888/3480246. In fact, you can getMessageID () and store that value after send ()